# cordova rengle starter react/redux/typescript

Tags: cordova, reactjs

I started learning react. I use this starter 
https://github.com/rangle/typescript-react-redux-starter
What I need is move this app to cordova. 
I move `dist` folder to cordova `www` folder also added 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` to `index html`.

What is wrong in android application I have 
ack.

> file:///vendor.b6e77a9d795632fab9b3.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   file:///app.b6e77a9d795632fab9b3.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="/vendor.b6e77a9d795632fab9b3.js"></script>
<script src="/app.b6e77a9d795632fab9b3.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you plost you project structure and its contents?

Comment: the webpack is have flat www folder structure just
www/
 ..index.html, venodor.xxx.js and app.xxx.js 
Ii sems  the problem is with file getting file not by host file get, but i not shure how solve it

Comment: venodor.xxx.js and app.xxx.js are available in project root WWW folder?

Comment: yes.
When I manualy add change src to  src="./vendor.fb93f74341af183cd021.js">  file is visable :)
but I have another problem with css policy. Additionality only hash route work. But I think this problem is solve :)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it.
solution is  change src link from

```
<script src="/app.b6e77a9d795632fab9b3.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="./app.b6e77a9d795632fab9b3.js"></script>
```

but the only working rect route is hash